# Laravel says my public function is still undefined

Tags: php, laravel

pretty new to Laravel and still kind of a noob at PHP. Following along with a tutorial. I have a model named User.php that creates a public function.

```
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

And so I'm referencing it in my controller as such:
`auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);`
But it's giving me this error saying **"Undefined method 'posts'. intelephense(1013) [19,29]"**

Why is it undefined, from what I understand a public function should be accessible right? Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the `auth()` and `user()` functions? What does `user()` return?

Comment: Intelephense is not a PHP error. It comes from your editor, probably VSCode. It could be wrong, did you try to execute the code ? You should have a better error.

Comment: Ignore this type of error from VSCode